# control react-router navigation using redux middleware

Tags: reactjs, redux, middleware, react-router-v4

With the help of a Redux-middleware function im displaying a Warning Modal when **navigating away from the play page**.

The problem is i can't control the navigation at this point. The page is changed before the modal is showing up.

Any way i could stop the router from navigating and decide based on the modal choice?

[image]

```
middleware.push(routeIntrerceptor);

.....

const routeIntrerceptor = ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
  const state = getState();
  const location = state.router.location.pathname;

  if (action.type === '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE' && location.includes('play')) {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_DIALOG_TOGGLE' });
  }
  next(action);
};

export default routeIntrerceptor;
```

Comment: Is there some requirement for using redux for it? If it's not than you can use a built-in `<Prompt/>` component of react-router. More details and examples are here https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions.

Comment: And even more, if you are using `connected-react-router` look at this examples, I think they would be helpful https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/blob/master/FAQ.md#how-to-navigate-with-redux-action

Comment: @IvanBurnaev i tried using <Prompt/> , but i need it customized and that's too much pain from what i've tried. Your second post could help though!

Comment: Yeah, one thing. I think, if you want to interrupt some action you shouldn't pass it into the `next(action)` function. Try to put `next` into `else` block.

Comment: Moving the next(action) to else is causing a weird effect. The page is visually being changed, but the location (state.router.location.pathname) always remains the same. I don't have a lot of experience with redux-middleware.
PS: I'm not forced to use redux, but i thought it would be really awesome if it would work this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent the user from navigating away from a page you can use the `<Prompt />` it comes with react-router.

Check the documentation of react-router -

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions

Answer (score 0):

You could take a different approach and use Route render method instead of the middleware.

You could create shouldRender function, and check it before changing to other pages.

```
const mapStateToProps = state =>{
  const shouldRender = () => {
     if(location.includes('play') && !state.isDialogVisible){
     return false
     }
     return true
  }
  return {
    ....
    shouldRender
  }
}
```

```
<Route 
    path="/some_other_page"
    render={() => {
      if(shouldRender()}{ 
        return <SomeOtherPage/>
      }else {  
        openDialog()
        return <Redirect to={{pathname: "/play"}} />
      }
  }
/>
```

Comment: Interesting, but i don't see how i can influence the route change with a modal.

Comment: Just like with any other buttons :) 
I'm not sure I understand the problem that you are implying

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [react-router-navigation-prompt](https://github.com/ZacharyRSmith/react-router-navigation-prompt) , because i need the `<Prompt/>` to be styled.
However, this does not answer my question regarding a redux-middleware solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a promise:

```js
middleware.push(routeIntrerceptor);
    
.....

const routeIntrerceptor = ({dispatch, getState}) => next => action => {
  const state = getState();
  const location = state.router.location.pathname;

  if (action.type === '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE' && location.includes('play')) {
    dispatch({ type: 'SET_DIALOG_TOGGLE' });
    return Promise.resolve();
  }
  next(action);
};

export default routeIntrerceptor;
```